# How to exclude some instructions when compiling C code for arm v6 core using gcc?

Tags: gcc, armv6

When I am compiling C code for ARM v6 core, I don't want to use 'half-word' instructions like 'strh' or 'ldrh', because some of the peripherals don't support half-word access, they can only support APB3 bus, which strobe is always all ones. When cpu write 4-bytes data to 0x40001040 with strobe '0b1100', the lower 2 bytes of 0x40001040~0x40001043 will be written, too.
So How can I exclude some of the instructions in ARM v6 arch when compiling C code using gcc? Is there any option in gcc?

I try to compile C code for ARM v6 mechine using GCC, but I want to exclude some of the instructions from ARM v6 Arch